# How many cases of stoning are documented in the hadiths?

Tags: hadith, rajm

How many cases of stoning are documented in the hadith? Were all of them carried out on the Jews or were Muslims also stoned for adultery?

Comment: As far as I know 2 muslims and 2 jews cases. In muslim cases, both were insisted by the people who did adultery. In total 3 muslims were stoned.

Comment: @smttsp I think there's a hadith about a Muslim man being stoned to death after being convicted of adultery via his own confession while Muhammad was somewhere else, and the man tried to run away; when Muhammad came back, the sahaba told him, and he asked why they didn't stop stoning him since running away should be interpreted as him retracting his confession. Is that one of the cases you remember?

Comment: @G. Bach, yes it is one of them but I want to note that the man insisted for the punishment. prophet Muhammad pbuh avoided the punishment and told the sahabe that he should repent, Allah will forgive any sins but he constantly insisted for the punishment. I dont know why prophet wasnt there but when he learnt he got so angry that his carotid was visible (this is mentioned of the hadith but I m not sure if it is carotid or veins on face)

Comment: If I am not wrong, most cases were through confession only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least four cases of Muslims being stoned to death according to the *Hadd* of *Zina* (adultery) in the time of the Prophet, as recorded in the major Hadith collections.

[Maiz ibn Malik](https://islamqa.info/en/9292) of the tribe of Aslam:

> A man from the tribe of Aslam came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and confessed
> that he had committed an illegal sexual intercourse. The Prophet (ﷺ)
> turned his face away from him till the man bore witness against
> himself four times. The Prophet (ﷺ) said to him, "Are you mad?" He
> said "No." He said, "Are you married?" He said, "Yes." Then the
> Prophet (ﷺ) ordered that he be stoned to death, and he was stoned to
> death at the Musalla. When the stones troubled him, he fled, but he
> was caught and was stoned till he died. The Prophet (ﷺ) spoke well of
> him and offered his funeral prayer. [[Saheeh Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6820)]
>
> When Ma'iz bin Malik came to the Prophet (in order to confess), the
> Prophet (ﷺ) said to him, "Probably you have only kissed (the lady), or
> winked, or looked at her?" He said, "No, O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)!" The
> Prophet said, using no euphemism, "Did you have sexual intercourse
> with her?" The narrator added: At that, (i.e. after his confession)
> the Prophet (ﷺ) ordered that he be stoned (to death). [[Saheeh
> Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6824)]
>
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) asked Ma’iz b. Malik : Is what I have heard
> about you is true? He said: What have you heard about me? He said: I
> have heard that you have had intercourse with a girl belonging to the
> family of so and so. He said: Yes. He then testified four times. He
> (The prophet) then gave order regarding him and he was stoned to
> death. [[Sunan Abu Daud](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/75)]

Unnamed woman:

> Then a woman of Ghamid, a branch of Azd, came to him and said:
> Messenger of of Allah, purify me, whereupon he said: Woe be upon you;
> go back and beg forgiveness from Allah and turn to Him in repentance.
> She said: I find that you intend to send me back as you sent back
> Ma'iz. b. Malik. He (the Holy, Prophet) said: What has happened to
> you? She said that she had become pregnant as a result of fornication.
> He (the Holy Prophet) said: Is it you (who has done that)? She said:
> Yes. He (the Holy Prophet) said to her: (You will not be punished)
> until you deliver what is there in your womb. One of the Ansar became
> responsible for her until she was delivered (of the child). He (that
> Ansari) came to Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) and said the woman of Ghamid has
> given birth to a child. He (the Holy Prophet) said: In that case we
> shall not stone her and so leave her infant with none to suckle him.
> One of the Ansar got up and said: Allah's Apostle, let the
> responsibility of his suckling be upon me. She was then stoned to
> death. [[Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/29/34)]
>
> "A woman from Juhainah confessed before the Prophet (ﷺ) that she had
> committed adultery, and she said: 'I am pregnant.' So the Prophet (ﷺ)
> called for her guardian and said: 'Be good to her and if she gives
> birth to her child then tell me.' So he did so, and then he (ﷺ) gave
> the order that her clothes be bound tightly around her. Then he
> ordered her to be stoned and she was stoned. Then he performed
> (funeral) Salat for her. So 'Umar bin Al-Khattab said to him: 'O
> Messenger of Allah! You stoned her then you prayed for her?!' He said:
> 'She has repented a repentance that, if distributed among seventy of
> the people of Al-Madinah, it would have sufficed them. Have you ever
> seen something more virtuous than her sacrificing herself for the sake
> of Allah?'"  [ [Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/29/36) ]

Unnamed woman who committed adultery with an unmarried man:

> A bedouin came to the Prophet (ﷺ) while he (the Prophet) was sitting,
> and said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Give your verdict according to
> Allah's Laws (in our case)." Then his opponent got up and said, "He
> has told the truth, O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Decide his case according
> to Allah's Laws. My son was a laborer working for this person, and he
> committed illegal sexual intercourse with his wife, and the people
> told me that my son should be stoned to death, but I offered
> one-hundred sheep and a slave girl as a ransom for him. Then I asked
> the religious learned people, and they told me that my son should be
> flogged with one-hundred stripes and be exiled for one year." The
> Prophet (ﷺ) said, "By Him in Whose Hand my soul is, I will judge you
> according to Allah's Laws. The sheep and the slave girl will be
> returned to you and your son will be flogged one-hundred stripes and
> be exiled for one year. And you, O Unais! Go to the wife of this man
> (and if she confesses), stone her to death." So Unais went in the
> morning and stoned her to death (after she had confessed). [[Saheeh
> Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6835)]

Unnamed man who committed rape:

> A women went out during the time of the Prophet (ﷺ) to go to Salat,
> but she was caught by a man and he had relations with her, so she
> screamed and he left. Then a man came across her and she said: 'That
> man has done this and that to me', then she came across a group of
> Emigrants (Muhajirin) and she said: 'That man did this and that to
> me.' They went to get the man she thought had relations with her, and
> they brought him to her. She said: 'Yes, that's him.' So they brought
> him to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ), and when he ordered that he be
> stoned, the man who had relations with her, said: 'O Messenger of
> Allah, I am the one who had relations with her.' So he said to her:
> 'Go, for Allah has forgiven you.' Then he said some nice words to the
> man (who was brought). And he said to the man who had relations with
> her: 'Stone him.' Then he said: 'He has repented a repentance that, if
> the inhabitants of Al-Madinah had repented with, it would have been
> accepted from them.'"  [[Sunan Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/29) and [Jami Tirmizi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/17/37)]

Finally, the Jewish couple who committed adultery and were stoned according to the law of the Torah:

> A Jew and a Jewess were brought to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) on a charge
> of committing an illegal sexual intercourse. The Prophet (ﷺ) asked
> them. "What is the legal punishment (for this sin) in your Book
> (Torah)?" They replied, "Our priests have innovated the punishment of
> blackening the faces with charcoal and Tajbiya." Abdullah bin Salam
> said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ), tell them to bring the Torah." The
> Torah was brought, and then one of the Jews put his hand over the
> Divine Verse of the Rajam (stoning to death) and started reading what
> preceded and what followed it. On that, Ibn Salam said to the Jew,
> "Lift up your hand." Behold! The Divine Verse of the Rajam was under
> his hand. So Allah's Apostle ordered that the two (sinners) be stoned
> to death, and so they were stoned. Ibn `Umar added: So both of them
> were stoned at the Balat and I saw the man sheltering the woman.
> [[Saheeh Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6819)]