# Which verse abrogates the verse on stoning?

Tags: hadith, rajm

Many hadith proves the verse of rajm(stoning) is abrogated. But my question is the verse is abrogated with which verse? Please give the reference in your answer.

Comment: It is claimed to have been abrogated in recitation but not in ruling, hence there isn't a verse which abrogated it.

Comment: The ahadith in first place confirm the former existence of such a vers or verses. They don't prove the abrogation of the ruling.

Answer (score 3):

Stoning does not appear in the Qur'an ([ref.](http://www.irfi.org/articles/articles_51_100/stoning_to_death_does_not_appear.htm)).  It's instead mentioned in multiple hadith, e.g.:

> The Jews brought a man and a woman who had committed illegal sexual intercourse, to the Prophet and the Prophet ordered them to be stoned to death, and they were stoned to death near the mosque where the biers used to be placed.
>   <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 7332](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/61)</sub>

Further ahadith are cited in: [How many cases of stoning are documented in the hadiths?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38240/17163)  The closest the Qur'an mentions is:

> The [unmarried] woman or [unmarried] man found guilty of sexual intercourse - lash each one of them with a hundred lashes ...
>   <sub>[Qur'an 24:2](http://%20https://quran.com/24/2)</sub>

I don't believe stoning is considered "abrogated" by scholars ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rajm) surveys the major schools of thought), e.g.:

> ...stoning is due upon a married person (men and women) who commit Zina if there is a clear evidence...
>   <sub>[IslamWeb](https://islamweb.net/en/fatwa/85019/)</sub>

There are some arguments against stoning, although they go against the majority of scholars.  [Opposition to Rajm (Stoning): Analysis and Refutation](https://icraa.org/opposition-to-rajm-stoning-analysis-and-refutation/) debates this issue.

Comment: verse of stoning(rajm) is abrogated and many scholars agree to this. They also say that the ruling(e.g. stoning the adulterer) is a sunnah. But my question is this verse is replaced with which verse? Please clarify it.

Comment: as a matter of fact, umar, ubadah and a number of early muslims who met the prophet claimed that stoning was in fact revealed as part of the Qur'an.

Answer (score 2):

The verse of stoning was never abrogated in practice of Muslims almost all Muslim sects: Sunni, Shi'a and Ibadi confirm the punishment of stoning for married adulterers.
If there was a verse abrogating it, this ruling would not remain or at least would be adjusted, which is not the case.

What was abrogated was the recitation this means in the final "update" of the qur'an the prophet () didn't confirm that this verse should remain in surat al-Ahzab and therefore in the qur'an we have at hand and people recite since 14 centuries this verse is nowhere mentioned. However several sahabah confirmed that it was part of the qur'an and mentioned similar wordings of this abrogated verse.

Further the ruling of stoning adulterers is still present in the old testament.
This might be regarded as a further evidence for the ruling. However both some early and contemporary scholars discussed and questioned the existence of such a verse due to different reasons like the wording mentioned in the ahadith which had small differences (this reason could rather be refuted easily) and doesn't seem to smoothly fit to the words of the qur'an. Beside this the remaining interpretation of the rule has an issue if it would be applied on slaves as they should get half the punishment of free people which doesn't make sense in case of a death sentence.

Comment: the concept of "abrogated in reading but not in practise" sounds extremely dubious to begin with this concept cant be proven from the quran and sunnah. in fact if we stick to the Quran and Hadiths the only meaning of "abrogation" that can be derived is one of total replacement